# Adamantium in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men, adamantium

Due to Fox having the rights to X-Men, there are few restrictions to what can be mentioned and eluded to in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (eg: 'Mutants'). Does this restriction stretch to Adamantium? I understand that -in the comics- some incarnations of Ultron were made of the substance.

I'm **not** asking, in the upcoming movie, Avengers: Age of Ultron, if Ultron will be made of Adamantium. I would simply like to know if it is/was ever an option?

Comment: No idea how accurate it is, but the Marvel Cinematic Universe Wikia entry for [Captain America's Shield](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America%27s_Shield) says this: "The second shield was originally supposed to be made out of a mix between Vibranium (for absorbing vibrations) and Adamantium (for its near indestructibility). **However, since 20th Century Fox holds the rights to Adamantium as part of the X-Men franchise, this was changed to be completely made out of Vibranium.**" There's no source for that info though.

Comment: My understanding is that the "ban" on the use of the word Mutant is a gentleman's agreement between the two studios rather than an issue of legal rights.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two distinct questions here;

1) ***Can* Marvel freely use the term Adamantium to describe Ultron's coverings?** - Yes, absolutely they can. Not only has the metal been a part of their existing comic properties but the word itself isn't trademarked. I can use it, you can use it, **anyone can use it.**

[image]

2) ***Will they* describe his coverings as Adamantium?** - Probably not. Since the metal is so heavily associated with Wolverine in the X-Men Cinematic series, it's more likely that they'll describe Ultron's coverings as another metal (such as Vibranium) or simply leave the question unanswered, in the same way that we still don't know [what the Winter Soldier's arm is made of.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/65736/20774)

Comment: Does that mean they can freely use the name 'Magneto' or the word 'Mutant'? I was under the impression that there were restrictions due to the licencing agreement? Just wondering if Adamantium came under those restrictions too, or is my question based on a false premise?

Comment: Yes and No. Magneto is a trademark of the Marvel Entertainment Group whereas the word Mutant is free to be used by anyone. The terms Adamantium and Adamantine predate their use in the Marvel and DC comics and are therefore free to be used by anyone.

Comment: I did not know that about Adamantium. I assumed it was created by Marvel. Consider the answer accepted!

Comment: I was under the impress that they aren't allowed to use the term mutant to describe any characters due to their own intercompany contracts.  This can superceed the patent law if what they are avoiding is a breach of contract claus.

Comment: @kaine - This is part of a pre-existing contractual agreement between the two studios over the use of certain terms and characters, not something based on any sort of copyright. I can happily use the terms Adamantium or Mutant if I want to; http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=Q8Z5bLGu

Comment: I am taking advantage of my right to use a non-trademarked word: ADAMANTIUM!