# Was the Black Panther's Suit ever made from Adamantium?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, black-panther

In *Captain America: Civil War*, after a brief scuffle between Captain America and the Black Panther, the Cap makes a passing comment about the material of the Panther's suit - suggesting it is made from Vibranium.

There are several references between the Black Panther and the Vibranium in the MCU (AoU - Klaw stole the Vibranium and has a Wakandan brand), and there are mentions of this in the comics as well.

However, from my memory, the Black Panther suit was originally made from Adamantium, similar to Wolverine. Is this true? If so, why was it changed?

Comment: I don't think that Adamantium exists in the MCU. I'm not sure about this and one of our more MCU focussed users will confirm.

Comment: Related: [Adamantium in the MCU?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/75746/21267)

Comment: would a suit made from adamantium not be to heavy to wear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### In the comics, the Black Panther has a vibranium-weave suit.

Directly from [Marvel Universe](http://marvel.com/universe/Black_Panther_(T%27Challa)#ixzz48PPmWDQU)

> T'Challa's Vibranium-weave uniform absorbs the kinetic force of impacts, rendering him bulletproof. His costume's gloves can generate energy daggers and house anti-metal claws that dissolve other metals on contact.

[image: suity suit suit]

There is no mention that I know of, or can find of Black Panther ever having an *adamantium* suit or weapons.

Of note, the Black Panther was introduced in 1966, while adamantium did not appear until 1969 when it was part of Ultron's outer shell.

Comment: What does the word "abbott" mean in the speech bubble?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 he's referring to his outfit. An abbot is basically a full-body covering

Comment: @Ben From the context, I thought that's what he meant, but I've not heard that term before. Thanks for the clarification :)